# CSS animate on html form

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, forms

Here's an example of what I am trying to recreate: https://www.hioscar.com/get-quote/

- When a user has finished entering information into the input area or selected an option the current line will animate (using translate & opacity, I believe) and the next line will come into view.

I've started something very basic just to get a feel for how it's meant to work using on hover but I'm not sure on how to complete replicate this animation in my own form.

```css
div {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -300px);
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: opacity 0.05s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello, I am a very basic example</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you had several problems, you were only animating opacity and if you move the div from under the mouse cursor when you hover it, it won't work.

So I activated all transitions, not just opacity, made the div as tall as the browser, and used the div's internal padding.

```css
body, html {
  /* needed so that the div can also be 100% of window */
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 500px;
}
    
div:hover {
  padding-top: 300px;
  transition: all 0.05s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello, I am a very basic example</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the link shows the full animation we are trying to recreate. Do you know how we can recreate the complete animation?

Comment: Yes, they add this `transform: translateY(calc(50vh + -130px));` as style to the animated element just after the page has loaded, depending on your infrastructure that can be done in a number of ways, but usually you trigger a javascript function on document ready that sets this style.

Comment: Basically, instead of applying the animation with css hover, you apply it with javascript on page load. In my example code just switch the 500px with the 300px (to make it come down, instead of up), turn div:hover into a class name, like .animation, and use jQuery or whatever to apply that class to the div after page load.